# JavaMail POP3 over SSL Connect failed;

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-mail

I would like to download mail by accessing the POP3 server SSL is configured on the local environment, but we failed.

What steps do you need to take when connecting?

Exception

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Sample code

```
Properties props = new Properties();
final String HOST = "host";
final String PROTOCOL = "pop3";
final String PORT = "995";
String username = "user";
String pass = "password";
final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
props.setProperty("mail.pop3.port", PORT);
props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", PORT);
URLName urln = new URLName(PROTOCOL, HOST, Integer.parseInt(PORT), null, username, pass);

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore(urln);

store.connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the property mail.pop3.ssl.trust

```
props.setProperty("mail.pop3.ssl.trust", "*"); // Trust all Servers
```

You should also be able to only set it to your specific server, test with * before though

```
props.setProperty("mail.pop3.ssl.trust", HOST);
```

Comment: That's almost right.  See [this FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#installcert) for details.  See also this [list of common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) to clean up your code.